# Mysqli data to file transformation

Tags: php, json

I got the following code in my project fetching data (currently only a single row) from a database and writing them in a file

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
$sqlTot = $sqlRec = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `prisoners` ";
$sqlTot .= $sql;
$sqlRec .= $sql;

$sqlRec .=  " ORDER BY id";
$queryTot = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlTot) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
$queryRecords = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch prisoner data");

$data = array();
//iterate on results row and create new index array of data
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($queryRecords) ) { 
    $data[] = $row;
}   

file_put_contents("data.txt", print_r($data, true));
?>
```

However this writes the specific row as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Παπαευθυμίου (ή Παπαδόπουλος)
            [2] => Χαράλαμπος
        )
)
```

whereas I would like it to output it like

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "lastname": "Παπαευθυμίου (ή Παπαδόπουλος)",
      "firstname": "Χαράλαμπος"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc) to get an associative array to get the column names.

Then use [`json_encode()`](https://secure.php.net/json_encode) to display as you want :

```
$data = array();
//iterate on results row and create new index array of data
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryRecords) ) { 
    $data['data'][] = $row;
}
file_put_contents("data.txt", json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Edit, as seen in your comments below (for greek (unicode) characters):

```
file_put_contents("data.txt", json_encode($data, 
       JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
```

Comment: Yes! That did it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ChristosMordons You're welcome. I've added the options for greek characters as seen in comments below. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) method to archieve this:

```
file_put_contents("data.txt", json_encode($data));
```

Comment: This is better, but it outputs [["1","Παπαευθυμίου (ή Παπαδόπουλος)","Χαράλαμπος"]]. 
It also requires the following modification for greek (unicode) characters: 

json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)